# how to remove black background for android launcher icon?

Tags: android, png, photoshop, android-icons

i've saved my icon as a png-32, with transparency checked and tried saving for web but the black background is still there. i've also saved as a nornmal png and still no good. i fixed this about 6 months ago but for the life of me i can't remember now.

any help would be great thanks

Comment: What device are you using? I've noticed the Galaxy Tab, for example, will add backgrounds to launchers, but seems to make exceptions.

Comment: You've set your alpha transparency correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The actual technique will depend somewhat on the application you're using, but it's very easy to do in Gimp (free).  You simply add a transparent layer, select the background and then delete it.  Here's a link that explains the process: http://www.fabiovisentin.com/tutorial/GIMP_transparent_image/gimp_how_to_make_transparent_image.asp.

If you're using a different tool, such as Photoshop, the exact process will of course be slightly different.  Hope this helps.

Comment: i'm using 2 samsung galaxy europas for a bluetooth poker app. if anyone wants to try it out, let me know. i'd love some feedback.  cheers for the response but it seems to have fixed itself. black background's gone. i did increase the file size again but that didn't work before so i don't think that's what fixed it. thanks.